# Learn a Weighted Average of Pre-Trained Neural Network Weights

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, ensemble-learning

I have multiple pre-trained neural networks with the same architecture and different weights. I want to take a weighted average of the weights in these networks to make one network of the same size (in an attempt to improve generalizability without sacrificing size).

To be clear: I only want to learn the weights for the average: NOT the weights inside the pre-trained networks.

This is what I have so far:

```
class Ensemble(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, modelWeights, model):
        super().__init__()

        self.modelWeights = modelWeights
        self.model = model

        self.w = self.add_weight(f'Weights', shape = (len(modelWeights),), initializer = initializers.Constant(1 / len(modelWeights)))
        self.b = self.add_weight('Bias', shape = (1,), initializer = 'zeros')

    def call(self, inputs):
        newWeights = []
        for weightsTuple in zip(*self.modelWeights):
            temp = []
            for weights in zip(*weightsTuple):
                weights = tf.convert_to_tensor(weights)
                temp += [tf.tensordot(weights, self.w, axes = [[0], [0]]) + self.b]

            newWeights += [temp]
    
        self.model.set_weights(newWeights)
        return self.model(inputs)
```

`modelWeights` is a list of `model.get_weights()`

Besides the error I'm currently getting (ValueError: Layer model weight shape (3, 4, 64) is not compatible with provided weight shape ()) I don't think keras is going to let me do `self.model.set_weights(newWeights)` inside the call function.

Does anyone have a better way to do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't get your approach. Do you want to average out the weights from e.g. 5 models, with an average per layer, after training? Why do you construct a model layer class for that? Why not average the weights in a normal function? A layer class is used in one model, and then it doesn't know the weights from the other models.

Comment: @mhenning I'm trying to implement a weighted average of the model weights, such that I can learn the weight for each model. I.E. (weights of model 1) * (learned scalar 1) + (weights of model 2) * (learned scalar 2) etc. Does that make sense?

Comment: I think @mhenning's point is that there's theoretically no reason this should work. From the perspective of model 1, model 2's weights are just random. It only makes sense to 1) learn the scaling weights, 2) condition the output layer (pre/post-softmax)

Comment: I never tried it myself, but there is a paper about (I think) that approach: https://arxiv.org/pdf/2203.05482v3.pdf. In it the authors used the average of an ensemble to improve the performance. Very interesting idea.

Comment: These are fine-tuned models which will have weights that are theoretically close (pretrained initializations identical, trained for small number of epochs); as such, the fine-tuned weights will have small variance so averaging makes a bit more sense. In general, it doesn't.

Comment: The "Model Soups" paper is where I got this idea. I have a very similar setup, which is why I think this will work. The only difference is that I want to optimize the weighting of this average using back prop.

Comment: Good observation erip. I also don't think it'll work with models trained from scratch.

Comment: That's a potentially very expensive operation. :-) You'll need O(num_parameters X num_models) in trainable weights. For, e.g., five BERT-large's that's 1.5B parameters; learning the weights probably wouldn't perform better than simply fine-tuning any of the individual models with the same data.

Comment: No, no, no, you misunderstand. One parameter per network. One scalar per network, which describes the weight of that particular network in the weighted average. Is that clearer?

Answer (score 1):

I hope I get your idea, otherwise correct me.
To average out the weights of multiple trained models you can do the following (example with 3 models):

```
models_weights = [model1.get_weights(), model2.get_weights(), model3.get_weights()]
models_scalars = [0.3, 0.2, 0.5]  # scalar weighting for model1, model2..

new_model_weights = [[layer_weight * scalar for layer_weight in model_weights] for model_weights, scalar in zip(models_weights, model_scalars)]
new_model_weights_mean = [np.sum(np.array(layer_weights),axis=0) for layer_weights in zip(*new_model_weights)]
# create new_model here..
new_model.save_weights(new_model_weights_mean)
```

Edit: The only other approach I can think of is to freeze all models and connect their output to a `Dense(1, use_bias=False)` node, with a kernel constrain that all weights has to be between 0 and 1 and sum up to 1. This way a model could potentially learn how much say has a network in the final decision. But this will not merge the network weights together and only weights the outputs.

Comment: This is close to what I'm thinking, but not quite. A) My issue is: How do I learn these "models_scalars"? That's what I was trying to do in the code snippet above, but I'm not sure how to do it inside a layer (so that I can optimize the "models_scalars" via backprop). B) I'm pretty sure to do a proper weighted average of the "models_weights" your "np.mean" should be "np.sum" (because you're already applying your multiplicative scalar), but that's nitpicky. Does that clarify my objective?

Comment: You're right about the mean -> sum, I fixed that. As for your idea, I'm not sure it is solvable. Even the authors in the paper I mentioned used "only" a greedy approach to iteratively soup their equally weighted models together. All I can think of is a grid search over the scalars, but to backpropagate these over the different models.. no idea. Maybe you can take a look into bayesian optimization.